# Generating HTML toggle buttons with JavaScript and initializing them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div:

```
<div id="div1">

</div>
```

And I'm trying to generate "toggle" buttons (http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) with JavaScript:

```
<script>
    var count = 1;

    function foo() {
        var newButton = "<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"" + count + "\" checked data-toggle=\"toggle\"><br>";
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML += newButton;
        $('#' + count).bootstrapToggle();

        // also tried re-initializing the first created button, this won't work either..
        //$('#1').bootstrapToggle();

        count = count + 1;
    }
    setInterval(foo, 4000);
</script>
```

This creates the buttons just fine, but those have to be initialized first by calling.

```
$('#1').bootstrapToggle();
```

The problem is, that when I have generated the first button and generate the second, the first one stops working. I have also tried to re-initialize the first button in the same div, but that won't work either.

Please, if there's a better way to do this I'd be glad to receive some help (or better, example code) on how to do this. The thing is that I cannot do this other way, because I'm generating these from JSON input.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the problem but `+=innerHTML` is a bad practice. Try using `createElement`. Also, `count = count +1` can be `count++`. Also i guess input tags needs `/>` at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rajesh says, the `+=innerHTML` is causing problems.

This will work:

```
<div id="container"></div>

var count = 1;

function createButton() {
  var newButton = "<input type='checkbox' id='" + count + "' checked data-toggle='toggle'><br>";
  $('#container').append(newButton);
  $('#' + count).bootstrapToggle();
  count = count + 1;
}

setInterval(createButton, 1000);
```

---

**Edit**: You can also tidy things up a little to lose the ugly `count` global:

```
function createButton() {
  $('<input/>', {
    type: 'checkbox',
    checked: 'checked',
    data: {
      toggle: 'toggle'
    }
  })
  .appendTo('#container')
  .bootstrapToggle();
}

setInterval(createButton, 1000);
```

Comment: Yup, that was the problem. Thanks! :)

Comment: No worries :) Hold on two seconds, I'm just updating my answer.